# pandas DataFrame.groupby with a tolerance

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Given the following bit of some data:

```
data = {'Object': ['objA', 'objB', 'objC', 'objD', 'objE'],
        'Length': [10.1, 10.02, 7.4, 6.24, 5.99]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Which results in the following dataframe:

```
Out[6]:
   Length Object
0   10.10   objA
1   10.02   objB
2    7.40   objC
3    6.24   objD
4    5.99   objE
```

I'd like to group the 'Length' column based on a +- tolerance. Doing so would give me the following groups. Something like the **psuedocode below**:

```
tolerance = .25
grouped = df.groupby(df['Length'] +- tolerance)
```

Which would result with a grouping similar to the one below:

```
{(10.10+-.25): [0L, 1L],
 (7.40+-.25):  [2L],
 (6.24+-.25):  [3L, 4L]}
```

Looking around, folks have suggested using **pd.cut** and predefining bins, however, given the true size of my dataset and the variability of the lengths, pre-computing the bin ranges seems to be a bit of a brute force solution. Does anyone out there have a more elegant/fast/pandas/numpy-esque solution?

Comment: You first need bins.  Otherwise, how do you differentiate between 10.10 +/- 0.25 and 10.02 +/- 0.25 on the following row?

Comment: When using pd.cut is the result always mutually exclusive in that a value can only exist in binA or binB, but never BOTH binA AND binB?

Comment: I agree with @Alexander. To get a 'feel' for the data I'd plot them in a histogram, with the bin size being your measurement resolution (0.01). You'll get a quick intuitive view on what your actual data are. If you are worried about speed and you really have a lot of data, I'd put them into a database, where speedy comparisons are solved for your by other people.

Comment: Seems like the binning way through pd.cut (or .hist) was creating mutually exclusive items. In this particular case, I need the overlaps in the bins. However, these responses were handy for a few other reports I needed to generate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [`intervaltree`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree/2.1.0) package on PyPI, instead of a pandas/numpy-esque solution.

The idea is to add each length +/- tolerance interval to the interval tree, having the interval map to the associated object.  Then, iterate over the lengths and query the interval tree.  This will give you all of the objects that have a tolerance interval containing the queried length.

```
from intervaltree import IntervalTree

t = IntervalTree()
for length, obj in zip(data['Length'], data['Object']):
    t[length-tolerance:length+tolerance] = obj

result = {}
for length in data['Length']:
    objs = [iv.data for iv in t[length]]
    result[length] = objs
```

The `result` dictionary is as follows:

```
{10.1: ['objA', 'objB'], 5.99: ['objD', 'objE'], 10.02: ['objA', 'objB'], 6.24: ['objD'], 7.4: ['objC']}
```

It's not quite in the format you specified, but it should be straightforward enough to make any changes to the format that you need.