# Duplicate rows based on condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, duplicates

I'm using pandas and I want to duplicate rows (col_a) on a if condition that is: if values in col_b are plus or minus 1 = duplicate.
or If col_b is <= 1 could be a possible solution instead of plus or minus 1 I will take it too.
Optimally, I would like to keep the number of "repetition", col_c for example.

```py
DF:
col_a   col_b
A000    10.16
A000    10.5
A000    10.9
A000    25.87
A000    26.5
B101    30.111
B101    8
```

```py
DF_Output:
col_a   col_b   col_c
A000    10.16   3
A000    25.87   2
B101    30.111  1
B101    8       1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas DataFrame.groupby with a tolerance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780448/pandas-dataframe-groupby-with-a-tolerance)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
grouper = df['col_b'].sort_values().diff().fillna(float('inf')).gt(1).cumsum()
grouped = df.groupby(grouper, sort=False, as_index=False)

result = grouped.agg(**{'col_a': ('col_a', 'first'),
                        'col_b': ('col_b', 'first'),
                        'col_c': ('col_a', 'size')
                        })
print(result)
>>>
  col_a   col_b  col_c
0  A000  10.160      3
1  A000  25.870      2
2  B101  30.111      1
3  B101   8.000      1
```